# Programmatically Adding UITapGestureRecognizer To UIViews in Outlet Collection

Tags: ios, uiview, swift4, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am working with a series of views stored in an outlet collection.

```
@IBOutlet var theViews: [UIView]!
```

In my viewDidLoad function I am looping over the collection of views during which I create a UITapGestureRecognizer and add it to the view.

```
for v in theViews {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.flipSingleView(sender:)))
    tap.delegate = self
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    v.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Here is the function that the selector points to:

```
@objc func flipSingleView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tapped")
}
```

Additional notes:

- User interaction is enabled for these views
- Breakpoint inside flipSingleView is never reached
- The View Controller implements UIGestureRecognizerDelegate (I've looked through the protocol and don't see a function that would be useful in this situation)
- Have Verified that all views in question have outlet connections to the outlet collection
- Nothing prints to the console

Comment: Your code is fine.  I tried it it the simulator and it works.  Make sure the parent view has `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned your views are in an outlet collection, so I'm assuming it looks something like this:

```
@IBOutlet var myViews: [UIView]!
```

Not sure you need everything you threw in there. Try this:

```
// In viewDidLoad
myViews.forEach{ view in
  let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(gesture:)))
  tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
  tap.delegate = self
  view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

For your handler:

```
  @objc func handleTap(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap")
  }
```

And lastly, put in a section for delegate methods, even if it's just empty:

```
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  // TODO: Fill in as needed
}
```

To figure out which view sent it, you could add a tag to the view.

Comment: You were absolutely right about removing the line setting tap.numberOfTouchesRequired. Any idea what the reason for this is? Is it that taps and touches conflict?

Comment: `var numberOfTouchesRequired: Int` from documentation says: "The number of fingers required to tap for the gesture to be recognized". I just eyeballed it and thought it looked odd. `numberOfTouchesRequired` defaults to one touch already, so you don't need to specify it unless it's something other than one.

Comment: Since it defaults to `1`, I fail to see how setting it to `1` hurts anything.  OP's code worked when I tried it.

Comment: You're right. I just looked at what he was trying to do and it seemed like a lot of code, so I tried to remove redundant code. His issue sounds like it could have been a fluke with the compiler or something. I don't think I deserve the answer :)

Comment: It may well have been. I went over the rest of the code this morning and confirmed that the only thing I changed was the aforementioned line setting up the required touch count just to see if I inadvertently made another change that resulted in the fix. With that said, none of the views implementing this functionality were registering touches prior to the change and after, they all registered touches and printed to the console. Compiler issue or not, I appreciate the help from both of you!